# GoDaddy and Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-management

im currently creating a website hosted at GoDaddy. I will have large amount of Data (700 GB per year) stored in a mysql database. Now, GoDaddy has a limitation of 1 GB per database, so im wondering how i should manage the data. I need the database (historical data) to visualize value-changes for different time ranges in the past.

Is there any (simple) solution or may i have to change the host?

One of the possible solutions could be to split the database, but im not sure what efficiency-consequences this could have.

Comment: The easiest is to move it to a new host and then update your application configuration to point to the new host.

Comment: 700 GB/yr is a lot of data, are you storing files in the DB?

Comment: @chris85 nah, just financial data, which i collect.